# How to get nested array of objects with same parameters

Tags: angular

Can some one please help i am trying to display all title and content in content array of article array

The below response is getting from database, I am equating that response to authordetails, just i gave name like this.

```
authordetails:any=[];

this.authordetails=[ 

          {"_id": "5c1a34ce5e2de421d8e060e5", "article":[ 
          {"content": [ 
                       {"content": "hh", "title": "Abstract" }, 
                       {"content": "gg", "title": "Introduction" }, 
                       {"content": "ii", "title": "Models" } 
         ];
```

I tried like this

```
this.authordetails[0].article[0].content[0].title
```

it means it shows only 0-object of title in content array.

But i need both title and content in content array of all objects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: add loop.

Comment: I am new to angular. Could you please help in clear Information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.authordetails.length; i++) {
      console.log('authordetails',this.authordetails[i]);
      for (let j = 0; j < this.authordetails[i].article.length; j++) {
        console.log('article',this.authordetails[i].article[j]);
        for (let k = 0; k < this.authordetails[i].article[j].content.length; k++) {
          console.log('content',this.authordetails[i].article[j].content[k]);
        }
      }
}
```

See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwpmme?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this (pseudocode)

```
for (i=0;this.authordetails[0].article.length;i++) {
    let innerObject = this.authordetails.article[i];
    let content = innerObject.content;
    let title = innerObject.title;
    // more logic goes here
}
```

Comment: It shows undefined, I wrote what u says and i tried this--->alert(this.title) & alert(article[0].content.title). Both are not working.

Comment: This is the logic that you should use. You may need to modify loop and belows. This is pseudocode

Comment: if it is not JSON you should convert it to JSON before loop by JSON.parse(this.authordetails). I also add [0] to "this.authordetails" at loop